# Why do I get this error (TypeError) when I loop through an object using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'city')

I'm trying to loop through address keys and values but failed then I tried to access one value at a time and I got that error. I'm new to React and JS. When I try to log that value, I get the answer with no problem but as soon as I want to print it out one the screen, the error pops up. I have tried possible way I could think of and find online, but sadly nothing worked.

```
//this is a component that is supposed to show details of each hero
const HeroPage = () => {
const { id } = useParams();
const [hero, setHero] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchHero = async () => {
      const res = await fetch(
        `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`);
      const data = await res.json();
      setHero(data);
    };

    fetchHero();
  }, [id]);

  const address = hero.address;

  return (
    <div className="card-container-page box">
      <div className="box-middle">
        <h1>{hero.name}</h1>
        <h3>{hero.email}</h3>
        <h3>{hero.phone}</h3>
        <h3>{address.city}</h3>
// I have also tried the following code 
        {Object.keys(hero).map((keyName, i) => (
          <li className="card-container" key={i}>
            <span className="input-label">
              key: {i} Name: {hero[keyName]}
            </span>
          </li>
        ))}

      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HeroPage;
```

```
//JSON response I get

[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  }]

//https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
```

Comment: Please show the *relevant* code. There's no loop here.

Comment: Unrelated, but your useEffect should also depend on `hero` and `setHero`, in addition to `id`

Comment: const { id } = useParams();
  const [hero, setHero] = useState({});

I used map() to loop through it and didn't work.

Comment: Please edit the question to show what you tried.

Comment: @Codebling I just edited the code to include what I have tried before. I don't understand why.

Comment: @Codebling I'm still learning React. Would you mind telling me how did you determine which ones useEffect should depend on in addition to ```id```

Comment: Sure! It's easy - it depends on anything you use inside the function. Since you use `setHero`, you need to depend on that. Dependency on `hero` was a mistake, so ignore that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your JSON response is an Array of objects.

This code will set that JSON response to the Hero state variable.

```js
    const fetchHero = async () => {
      const res = await fetch(
        `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`
      );
      const data = await res.json();

      setHero(data);
```

The type of hero is now an Array. So this line will be undefined:

```js
  const address = hero.address;
```

Instead, try accessing the first element of the array, like this:

```js
  const address = hero[0].address;
```

If we were to refactor this into a working component, you would write something like this.

```js
const HeroPage = (props) => {
  const [hero, setHero] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchHero = async () => {
      const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`);
      const data = await res.json();

      setHero(data);
    };

    fetchHero();
  }, [id]);

  if (hero === undefined) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div key={hero.id} className="card-container-page box">
      <div className="box-middle">
        <h1>{hero.name}</h1>
        <h3>{hero.email}</h3>
        <h3>{hero.phone}</h3>
        <h3>{hero.address.city}</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HeroPage;
```

Edit: re-working the example with the assumption that hero is an object.

Notice the check to see if hero === undefined. This is necessary because when state is initialized its value is undefined, before fetchHero gets a response and saves it in the state variable.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried the code above and I get this error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'address')

Comment: this the top part of my component.   const { id } = useParams();
  const [hero, setHero] = useState({});

Comment: The code above gives me the error I had previously when I tried to run it with map
"TypeError: hero.map is not a function"
This page is supposed to show details of one single hero, and it does that until I want to access nested objects like the address.

Comment: @davidio Are you certain of the response shape for fetchHero? You gave an example response for `//https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`, but in fetchHero you have `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`. I suspect that fetchHero returns a single object, and not an array?

Comment: @davidio I have updated my example code with the assumption that fetchHero returns an object and not an Array.

Comment: Thank you very much!! It works perfectly now, I greatly appreciate it! Learned a lot from this

Comment: @davidio glad to help!